# Takes time to set textview on OnSelectedItem of Spinner

Tags: android, listview, textview, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

Getview method of adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
    tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    id = Integer.parseInt(values.get(position));
    tvName.setText(database.getItemName(id));
    spQuantity = (Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spQuantity);
    spQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selectedQuantity = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
                    .toString();
            int selectedPrice = database.getPrice(id, selectedQuantity);
            Log.d("selectedPrice",""+selectedPrice); //showing correct value
            tvPrice.setText("Rs. " + selectedPrice); //not working
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    quantityList = database.getQuantityList(id);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.spinner_item_black, quantityList);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spQuantity.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    buttonAddtoCart = (LinearLayout) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.buttonAddtoCart);
    buttonAddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (database.checkDuplicateCart(id)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Already added to cart",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                database.addtoCart(id);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
    return rowView;

}
```

Log shows the correct value fetched from the database. Everything else is working fine. But the TextView is not changing its value. Only the last row of listview's TextView is changing its value for first time. **But when we wait for some time(about 30 secs), the text view changes. Why this takes so much time?**

Comment: I think you should set text for price outside of onItemClick also.

Comment: Need to post the relevant layouts too, at least for R.layout.list_items.

Comment: @justDroid will it work when an item is selected.

Comment: Do you want to call this when you click on the list item?

Comment: @justDroid yes. when the selected item on the spinner changes. i want to change the text view

Answer (score 0):

Some times Spinner in listview will not work as like we want, try to save your selected value in local variable and set the value in text view, try my below answer
let me know it is working or not

//This must be initialize only once

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

//Try to initialize TextView each and every time inside the getView. i have tried with Base adapter its working fine

```
         @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                 String Spinnerselecteditem;


                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
               TextView tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
               TextView tvPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                id = Integer.parseInt(values.get(position));
                tvName.setText(database.getItemName(id));
                Spinner spQuantity = (Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spQuantity);


 quantityList = database.getQuantityList(id);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        R.layout.spinner_item_black, quantityList);
                dataAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spQuantity.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



                spQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String selectedQuantity = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
                                .toString();
                        int selectedPrice = database.getPrice(id, selectedQuantity);
                        Log.d("selectedPrice",""+selectedPrice); //showing correct value
        Spinnerselecteditem = String.ValueOf(selectedPrice); //save it in a local variable 

     tvPrice.setText("Rs. " + Spinnerselecteditem);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });




              LinearLayout  buttonAddtoCart = (LinearLayout) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.buttonAddtoCart);
                buttonAddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (database.checkDuplicateCart(id)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Already added to cart",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            database.addtoCart(id);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return rowView;

            }
```

Comment: will this set the textview each time when item is selected?

Comment: Check it out my updated answer, also you are doing heavy process in getview  thats why it took huge time to update, try to retrieve database value in constructor of your adapter